# Generic way to use SQL Server WITH NO LOCK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

When I prefer to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` in all the SQL queries inside a specific large stored procedure, is there a generic way to use it for all the specific stored procedure statements, or I should use `WITH (NOLOCK)` for every individual query?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: This not not just an optimization, it is likely to make the application incorrect.

Comment: @usr, I agree, but I was really referring to the motivation to make such changes in the first place, not so much about this specific one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set the [Transaction Isolation Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED
```

However, don't forget that NOLOCK means your queries can potentially return dirty or duplicated data, or miss out data altogether. If it's an option for you, I would suggest investigating the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option to allow you to avoid locking issues while returning queries with consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the following syntax:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

I found this by looking at the NOLOCK table hint located here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx. The WITH(NOLOCK) table hint is equivalent to setting the isolation level to be READ UNCOMMITTED. Here's the snippet from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

NOLOCK Is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED. For more information, see READUNCOMMITTED later in this topic.